# How to find best fitting variable given two correlating variables and an outcome in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability

I have 9 variables and a final rate, in this case I will call the variables (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I) and the final rate Z. It is given that variables A, B and one other variable from (C...I) together are good predictors of Z. I have the data in a spreadsheet for 12 years for all of these variables as well as the rate.

I need to find a formula so I can test this. I've been trying for hours to use MatLab to use Multiple Variable Linear Regression w/ least squares method but I just can't seem to find information, get correlating data or be sure that it is proper. I'm also open to using other methods such as predictive distribution, kernels, but I do need to use the least squares method and have a general formula I can show my work with.

I'm thinking of doing a formula such as `Z = (mean(z) - b1*A - b2*B - b3*(VAR)) + b1A + b2B + b3C` (where VAR is tested for each other variable) but I'm not sure how to do this on matlab or if that is even the correct way. Please explain why you use that formula as well.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with using stepwise regression using A and B as your fixed variables and one other variable from C - I ?

Comment: @SomeGuy I'm not too sure how to do that on MatLab. I know to do Linear Regression you use '\' but how would you do that when your dependent variable (Y), the rate, is at the front, which leaves me struggling to find the output, or "equation" I should be putting into my MatLab script.

Comment: I just looked at the doc for stepwise and it seems you can't do this using it. One possible way to do it might be that you get the residuals from a linear regression on Z with A and B and then find which of the other variables have the highest absolute correlation with the residuals. That variable will give you the best regression if it enters the model

Comment: @SomeGuy How would you go about doing this on Matlab though, I've only learned Bayesian Regression and least squares style to solve this. I can also use Maximum Likelihood Estimate for Bernoulli Variables, multinomial mean/variance if any of those help.